# Android sdk download/update failing

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I'm trying to update and install the latest Android SDK (API 8) and keep getting the following error:

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I'm running on OS X 10.6.3  If I visit the url in a browser I'm not getting any errors about an untrusted cert.

edit:  I'm running Revision 5 of the Android SDK  and AVD manager (if that makes a difference)
edit:  Tried downloading the latest android sdk (revision 6) and running everything from the command line and still no dice.  I can only assume there's something either in my java installation or in os x on my machine.

Answer (score 24):

Try go to settings inside /tools/android and uncheck the "force https..."

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I don't see a settings tab/menu when I run the "Android SDK and AVD manager"  whether I start it up from the command line or from with in eclipse.

I've tried manually adding a site (http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml thinking this is the unsecured version?).  And now I'm getting this error:

Package Description
Android + Google APIs, API 8, revision 1
Requires SDK Platform Android API 8

Dependencies
This package depends on:
- Missing SDK Platform Android, API 8  

and then I get this error:

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I guess you can't get to settings from the eclipse "Android SDK and AVD manager"  Go to where you installed android on your mac. For me, I put it in my applications folder. Inside the android folder, you will see a "tools" folder, and in that folder, an "android" application. Funnily enough, its also named "Android SDK and AVD manager". THERE I see a settings tab on the left; and the "Force https" thing is over there

Comment: Ok, I'm blind.  I found the settings menu and unchecked force https  this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: This worked for me. I tried adding the non HTTPS version of the URL manually to the SDK manager in Eclipse but it only showed me the Google API packages in the list.  When I ran SDK Setup.exe from the SDK folder and changed the setting to "force https..." it showed me everything and I was able to download the platform, docs etc. Thanks for your help, you saved my day!

Comment: I had the same symptom but with a fresh Eclipse install.  The "Force hhtps..." was UNCHECKED by default.  I checked it and it corrected the problem.

Comment: This worked for me. On my Mac, the "force https..." option was in Preferences

Comment: my https was disable, so i first checked it, closed the SDK manager and unchecked it again and it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Resolved this issue in windows xp, open your android SDK manager you will find Android sdk tools checkbox underneath Tools checkbox.Select and update your Android sdk tool then you will not get this error again and now you can download api 8 for android 2.2

Answer (score 3):

Ok this worked for me so far (although it makes me nervous that I'll have future problems)
I downloaded the bundles straight from the site:
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-8_r01.zip
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.2_r01-macosx.zip

unzipped them and put the first one under the add-ons folder (where I had installed the android sdk   ../android-sdk-mac_86/add-ons/google_apis-8_r01)
unzipped the second one  and created the directory android-8 underneath ../android-sdk-mac_86/platforms  Taking the contents of the zip file and moving it into that directory (the first zip created an appropriately named directory, this one did not).

Now it shows up as installed.  Still wish I understood what the root problem is/was as I can't update any installed packages with out coming across the same initial error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I tried following Ovi Tisler's solution but the force https option was already deselected and nothing worked.

**Solution:**

I solved my my problem by updating the Android SDK tools and Android SDK android tools in the tools folder first. (Do not forget to checked for updates in Help->Check for updates after the installation). After that the SDK platform was listed along other API levels I did not have.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, This problem is mainly caused because ADB is unable to connect to the android servers to fetch updates. (If at home try turning off firewall)

- Goto folder Android SDK where your sdk is placed(in my case"D:/Android SDK/android-sdk-Windows").
- From this folder double click "SDK Manager.exe".
- When Android SDK and AVD Manager window opened then click Settings.
- In Proxy Settings, it will ask for a HTTP Proxy Server and HTTP Proxy Port.
- Enter the IP address and the port number being asked.
- In Misc Tab check "Force https://... "
- Turn off your firewall and temporarily disable your antivirus.

Hope this will surely work....

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7 I have the same issue, and many times android sdk downloads stucks forever. So I started sdk manager as administrator, and deactivated windows firewall, and my virus protection software. When doing that every thing goes fine, I was able to finish my android sdk downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using a mac, but for anyone who is on Windows and is getting this error then try going to the SDK and AVD Manager via eclipse instead of using the SDK Setup.exe.  This can be found under Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the reverse problem, non https and downloads were taking forever at 26KiB/s - It kept locking up using the manager. So I forced HTTPS and all is good now on Windows Vista

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user1544900.

In windows 7, I have to:

1. Temporarily turn off my windows firewall.
   a. (start -> run -> firewall.cpl) 
   b. Turn Windows Firewall on or off (hyperlink in left-hand menu)
   c. Choose Turn off Public firewall radio button in the lower section.
2. Restart eclipse by right clicking it and choosing the option to "Run as Administrator".
3. Start updating SDK.

** Don't forget to turn your firewall back on.